# I need guidance in this integral

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, partial-fractions

$$\int \frac{e^{2x}-2}{e^{2x}+7}\,\Bbb dx$$

I was trying:

$$\int \frac{e^{2x}}{e^{2x}+7}\,\Bbb dx -2\int \frac{1}{e^{2x}+7}\,\Bbb dx$$

$$= \frac{1}{2}\ln|e^{2x}+7| -2\int \frac{1}{(e^x)^2+(\sqrt{7})^2}\,\Bbb dx$$

$$= \frac{1}{2}\ln|e^{2x}+7|+ \frac{-2}{\sqrt{7}} \arctan\left(\frac{e^x}{\sqrt{7}}\right) +c.$$

However, the book answer says:

$$\frac{9}{14}\ln \left|e^{2x}+7\right|-\frac{2x}{7}+C.$$

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Check if both answers are equivalent

Comment: In the second integral, $\displaystyle\int\frac{1}{(\mathrm e^x)^2+(\sqrt7)^2}\mathrm dx$, your answer would be correct if it were $\displaystyle\int\frac{\mathrm e^x}{(\mathrm e^x)^2+(\sqrt7)^2}\mathrm dx$ instead.

Comment: @TobyBartels I thought the integral in that form  requires a 1 in the numerator

Comment: @TobyBartels is correct; remember it's $\displaystyle{\int f(u)du=\int f(u)\frac{du}{dx}dx}$

Comment: @samsamradas $\int\frac{1}{a^2+\color{red}{x^2}} \, \color{red}{dx}=\frac{1}{a}\arctan{\frac{x}{a}}+c$, in your case you have $e^x$ but are integrating with respect to $dx$ and not $de^x$.

Comment: It's $\displaystyle\int\frac1{x^2+a^2}\mathrm dx=\frac1a\arctan\Bigl(\frac xa\Bigr)+C$ or $\displaystyle\int\frac{\mathrm du/\mathrm dx}{u^2+a^2}\mathrm dx=\frac1a\arctan\Bigl(\frac ua\Bigr)+C$, not $\displaystyle\int\frac1{u^2+a^2}\mathrm dx=\frac1a\arctan\Bigl(\frac ua\Bigr)+C$. You'd need the same substitution that you did in the first integral, but it's not available this time.

Comment: I see my mistake, how should I approach the second integral?

Comment: Your substitution is wrong. If you are going to use $u=e^x$, then you must also use $du = e^x\,dx$ etc

Comment: @samsamradas a somewhat simpler way is to write $\int \frac{e^{2x}-2}{e^{2x}+7}dx=x-\int \frac{9}{e^{2x}+7}dx$ (skipped some steps). Then use $e^x=\sqrt{7}\tan u$.

Comment: @MPW :  The first integral is correct (as you can check by differentiating).  Although OP doesn't really want to do that integral, since that's the wrong way to split it up.

Comment: @TobyBartels : Softened my comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want to split it up like you did.  Instead, think of $ - 2 $ and $ 7 $ as the leading terms (which they are as $ x \to - \infty $), and do long division:
$$ \array { & \; - \frac 2 7 \hfil \\ 7 + \mathrm e ^ { 2 x } \! \! \! \! \! & ) \overline { - 2 + \mathrm e ^ { 2 x } } \hfil \\
& \quad \underline { 2 + \frac 2 7 \mathrm e ^ { 2 x } } \hfil \\
& \qquad \quad \! \frac 9 7 \mathrm e ^ { 2 x } \hfil } $$
so $$ \frac { - 2 + \mathrm e ^ { 2 x } } { 7 + \mathrm e ^ { 2 x } } = - \frac 2 7 + \frac { \frac 9 7 \mathrm e ^ { 2 x } } { 7 + \mathrm e ^ { 2 x } } \text . $$  This is how you want to split it up.  The first term here gives you the $ - \frac 2 7 x $, and the second term gives you the $ \frac 9 { 1 4 } \ln ( \mathrm e ^ { 2 x } + 7 ) $.  (Incidentally, you don't need the absolute value around $ \mathrm e ^ { 2 x } + 7 $, since that's always positive.)

Answer (score 8):

$\textbf{Hint:}$

$$\frac{e^{2x}-2}{e^{2x}+7} = \frac{\frac{9}{7}e^{2x}-\frac{2}{7}e^{2x}-2}{e^{2x}+7} = \frac{\frac{9}{7}e^{2x}}{e^{2x}+7} - \frac{2}{7}$$

Comment: what are you multiplying by in the first step?

Comment: @samsamradas there is nothing being multiplied

Comment: @samsamradas he isn't. $\frac{9}{7} u - \frac{2}{7} u = u.\quad $ +1, Nice answer btw.

Comment: what about 2 step?

Comment: $-\frac27e^{2x}-2=-\frac27(e^{2x}+7)$

Comment: IMO the motivation of the rewriting is not clear when written like this.

Comment: @GarethMa motivation comes with experience - you can either split the fraction by leaving a constant or an exponential on top. For integrating, we want the exponential leftover in the "remainder" term.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Clearly OP doesn't have the experience, otherwise it's trivial

Answer (score 5):

The trick to these is to note that $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(\log(e^x + 1)\right) = \frac{e^x}{e^x + 1}$, so here you have

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(\log(e^{2x} + 7)\right) = \frac{2e^{2x}}{e^{2x} + 7}
$$

To use this to solve your integral, we can express your fraction as a linear combination of $\frac{2e^{2x}}{e^{2x} + 7}$ and $1$. That is,

$$
\frac{e^{2x} - 2}{e^{2x} + 7} = c_1 \cdot \frac{2e^{2x}}{e^{2x} + 7} + c_2 \cdot 1
$$

We get $2c_1 + c_2 = 1$ and $7c_2 = -2$, so $\left(c_1, c_2\right) = \left(\frac{9}{14}, -\frac{2}{7}\right)$. Substituting, we can now integrate to get

$$
\int \frac{e^{2x} - 2}{e^{2x} + 7} \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{9}{14}\log\left(e^{2x} + 7\right) - \frac{2}{7}x + C
$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\def\arraystretch{2}\begin{array}{c|c}u=2\,x&x=\dfrac{u}{2}\\&\mathrm{d}x=\dfrac{1}{2}\,\mathrm{d}u\end{array}$$
$$\int{\dfrac{{e}^{u}-2}{2\,\left({e}^{u}+7\right)}}{\;\mathrm{d}u}$$
\begin{gathered}\;v={e}^{u}&\\\;\mathrm{d}v={e}^{u}\,\mathrm{d}u&\end{gathered}
$$\dfrac{1}{2}\int{\dfrac{v-2}{v\,\left(v+7\right)}}{\;\mathrm{d}v}$$
Grouping into sum of fractions
$$\dfrac{1}{2}\int{\dfrac{1}{v+7}-\dfrac{2}{v\,\left(v+7\right)}}{\;\mathrm{d}v}$$
$$\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\int{\dfrac{1}{v+7}}{\;\mathrm{d}v}-2\int{\dfrac{1}{v\,\left(v+7\right)}}{\;\mathrm{d}v}\right)=$$
$$=\dfrac{9\,\ln\left(\left|v+7\right|\right)}{14}-\dfrac{\ln\left(\left|v\right|\right)}{7}$$
Substitute back the values
$$\dfrac{9\,\ln\left({e}^{u}+7\right)}{14}-\dfrac{u}{7}$$
\begin{array}{c|c}u=2\,x&x=\dfrac{u}{2}\end{array}
$$\dfrac{9\,\ln\left({e}^{2\,x}+7\right)}{14}-\dfrac{2\,x}{7}$$

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

Another possible approach to compare with:
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{e^{2x} - 2}{e^{2x} + 7}\mathrm{d}x & = \int\frac{e^{2x} + 7}{e^{2x} + 7}\mathrm{d}x - 9\int\frac{1}{e^{2x} + 7}\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}

Based on such relation, notice as well that:
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{1}{e^{2x} + 7}\mathrm{d}x & = \int\frac{e^{x}}{e^{3x} + 7e^{x}}\mathrm{d}x\\\\
& = \int\frac{\mathrm{d}(e^{x})}{(e^{x})^{3} + 7e^{x}}\\\\
& = \int\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u^{3} + 7u}
\end{align*}

where you can apply the partial fraction decomposition method to calculate it.

Can you take it from here?